# Representation theory notation doubt

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

So I've been reading a little bit about representation theory from the book "Linear Representations of finite groups" and i have a question.
When the author writes , 'Let n be the order of G, and let V be a vector space of dimension n,
with a basis $(e_t)_ {t \in G}$ indexed by the elements t of G." Im not quite sure how to look at this , i dont think this is supposed to be $\mathbb{R} ^n$ , i guess my doubt is that i dont understand what he means with that basis notation. So any help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: What is the scalar field that the vector space is over? If it is the reals, you can look at it as $\mathbb R^n$, with an implicit group action.

Comment: He did mention that is a vector space over the complexs , so i guess i can look at it as $\mathbb{C}^n$ . But i really dont get what that notation is supposed to mean.

Comment: What notation are you confused about? The basis notation is basically saying that the elements of the basis are of the form $e_t$, where each $t\in G$

Comment: basis $(e_t)_{t \in G}$  indexed by the elements t of G , im not sure if this means just to consider the normal basis of $\mathbb{C}^n$ or something else.

Comment: No, it's some arbitrary basis, but if it makes sense to you to think about the normal basis, you can do so! Just remember that the basis elements are indexed by the elements of the group (probably in order to define a group action easily).

Comment: As long as you have a total order on the group, you can identify $V$ with $\mathbb{C}^n,$ yes.  Even without the total order, your $V$ will be isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^n,$ though.

Basically, the elements of $V$ will look like the **formal sums** $$\sum_{t\in G} c_t \cdot e_t$$ where $c_t$ are complex numbers and all but finitely many are $0$

Comment: @DonThousand Actually, I think it will be a disservice to the OP to have them think of this as the "normal" basis. Being able to understand this abstractly will be indispensible as they move forward with the book (I assume this is Serre's book by the title, which is not an easy one).

Comment: @BrianMoehring Why bring in a total order? You will always have such an order, but it will never be one that has anything to do with the group itself.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Fair enough. I haven't read the book so my bad.

Comment: Yes it is Serre's book , so i'm just supposed to think of it as an arbitary $n$ vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ where i can identify each basis element with an element of the group?

Comment: @PedroSantos Precisely.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft In $V$ there are canonical basis elements, but no canonical order.  In $\mathbb{C}^n$ there are both canonical basis elements and a canonical order to them.  That is, to make the identification, you implicitly must choose an order on $G$.  Whether this matters or not depends on the actual application, but I find many people deep into algebra have problems distinguishing equality from isormophism.  That's all I meant.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Ahh, that is true. I was trying to get away from the OP having to identify this with $\mathbb{C}^n$ at all as far as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll consider complex representations.

When I learned representation theory for the first time, it took me a while to realize why that definition makes sense, so I'll try to give an intuitive explanation.

I guess the sentence is from the definition of the regular representation of a group in section 1.2 (b) in Serre. Abstractly the vector space defined there is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^n$ and (in principle) $G$ just serves as the indexing set. Take some bijection from $G$ to $\{1, \ldots, n\}$ and you have the usual basis indexing. However, there is a good reason to index the basis by elements of the group:

As you have seen, the idea of a representation is to consider the group $G$ as acting on a finite dimensional vector space i.e. to consider the elements as matrices. Quite early on, one might ask if every group has such a representation and what restrictions there are and if there is a natural choice for a vector space and action etc. Indeed, there are two (somewhat) natural choices.

The first choice is the trivial representation (defined just in 1.2 (a) in Serre's book) where one represents every $g \in G$ by the $0$-matrix in $\mathbb{C}^{1 \times 1}$. The second one is more interesting:

Every group acts on itself by left multiplication $G \times G \rightarrow G: a.g \mapsto ag$. Now consider $\mathbb{C}^n =: V$ and associate to each element $g \in G$ a basis vector $e_g$ and define for any element $a \in G: a.e_g = e_{ag}$. This gives an action on $\mathbb{C}^n$ that is inherited by the groups action on itself. The elements $V$ are of the form $\sum_{g \in G} \lambda_g e_g$ and the explicit matrix representing an element $g \in G$ is entirely given by how $g$ acts on the other elements in $G$.

Notice now that we have a "natural" way of interpreting $G$ as a group of matrices. However, matrices can sensibly made into an algebra over $\mathbb{C}$ i.e. it does not only make sense to consider the action of $a \in G$ on an element $\sum_{g \in G} \lambda_g e_g$ but also to consider the action of $\sum_{a \in G} \lambda_a e_a$ on an element $\sum_{g \in G} \lambda_g e_g$. This action is uniquely determined by the action og $G$ on itself and the fact that that action on an element of $V$ needs to be linear. Ultimately this gives

$$ (\sum_{g \in G} \lambda_g e_g) \cdot (\sum_{h \in G} \mu_h e_h) = \sum_{g \in G} (\sum_{h \in G} \lambda_{gh^{-1}} \mu_h) e_g = \sum_{g,h \in G} (\lambda_g \mu_h) (e_{gh})$$

Compare this now to discrete convolution and notice why indexing by the group elements is sensible. Also explicitely look at the example where $G:=\mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z}$!

Considering the vector space $V$ together with the above defined multiplication makes it into a $\mathbb{C}$ algebra - the [group algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_ring) over $G$.

Also, if you are just starting out in representation theory, Serre's book may be a bit heavy/dry (at least it was for my taste). Maybe have a look at [James & Liebeck](https://books.google.de/books?id=PiJMr6kZP44C&printsec=frontcover&dq=james%20liebeck%20representation%20theory&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj2n-vA8vjjAhWIwqYKHYm7AtgQ6AEILDAA#v=onepage&q=james%20liebeck%20representation%20theory&f=false). They explicitely compute many examples and give a more concrete introduction. If you are looking for something more geared towards Lie Theory, consider [Fulton & Harris](https://books.google.de/books?id=qGFzi20nMcYC&printsec=frontcover&dq=fulton%20harris&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiRleq29PjjAhUUwcQBHYH0BfUQ6AEILDAA#v=onepage&q=fulton%20harris&f=false) (PDF available online).

Comment: Nice summary. It is also worth pointing out that this construction can be done for any set on which the group acts, giving the associated permutation representation. These are a nice starting point for building a lot of representations.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to G. Chiusole’s excellent answer, I wanted to give a (tiny) example.

Let $G = \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z} = \{0,1,2\}$. Note that $G$ has three elements, so we have three vectors in $\mathbb{C}^3$:

$$e_0 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}, \qquad e_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}, \qquad e_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}.$$

I know that $0$ is the identity element of $G$, so my representation of $G$ should send $0$ to

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}.$$

Now, since

$$\begin{cases} 1+0=1 \\ 1+1=2 \\ 1+2=0\end{cases}$$

my representation should send $1$ to a matrix $A$ such that

$$\begin{cases} Ae_0 = e_1 \\ Ae_1 = e_2 \\ Ae_2 = e_0\end{cases}$$

Thus, we need that

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 0&0&1 \\ 1&0&0 \\ 0&1&0 \end{bmatrix}.$$

Lastly, since

$$\begin{cases} 2+0=2 \\ 2+1=0 \\ 2+2=1\end{cases}$$

my representation should send $2$ to a matrix $B$ such that

$$\begin{cases} Be_0 = e_2 \\ Be_1 = e_0 \\ Be_2 = e_1\end{cases}$$

Thus, we need that

$$B = \begin{bmatrix} 0&1&0 \\ 0&0&1 \\ 1&0&0 \end{bmatrix}.$$