# Matrix form of a regular representation

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, characters

I was reading the book "Linear Representations of Finite Groups" by Jean-Pierre Serre, and in the begining of the chapter 2.4 about decomposition of the regular representation he states that

The character $X_{reg}(g)$ of the regular representation satisfies:
$X_{reg}(g)=\begin{cases}\mid G\mid&g=1_G\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

But i don't get why this is true. I'm having trouble making the matrix form of the regular representation and i think that it will will help me understand why this needs to be true.

Comment: The regular representation comes from the action of $G$ on itself by left multiplication. Make a vector space $kG$ with a basis indexed by the group elements $\{e_g \mid g \in G\}$. Then for each $g \in G$, define a linear map $L_g: kG \to kG$ on basis elements by $L_g(e_h) = e_{gh}$. Just try writing down these matrices for the groups of order 1, 2, and 3, and you should get the idea.

Comment: My problem is exactly writing down the matrices, i don't understand how to do it.

Can you explain to me?

Comment: Just to be sure, the matrix for the regular representation is
$\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & \dots  & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & \dots  & 0 \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & \dots  & 1
\end{bmatrix}$

If g = 1 and 0 otherwise, i can only think of a form like that, is that right?

Comment: It should definitely not be zero, a group representation always maps group elements to invertible matrices. Try a _concrete_ example with the group of order 3.

Comment: I didn't explain my reasoning right, i wanted to say that it is 1 in g, and 0 otherwise, so my matrix should have the form i writed, or my matrix is wrong?

Also, can you give me a concrete example?

Comment: You may be interested in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3319368/274352) as well.